# Can you explain this shape of a trunk?

Tags: trees

On this Wikipedia web page:

https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parque_periurbano_La_Barrosa

I found this photo:

[image]

Can you explain the reasons for such shape of this trunk?

Comment: It says in the text description of your link what the cause is - wind,so it must be growing in a place that gets strong cross winds.

Comment: The conifers in windy mountainous areas that I know are as straight as an arrow. @bamboo

Comment: @Stephie Some additional background: Pinus pinea (which is the same species as the pine in the picture) is sold by only one nursery in my area (even if 300km away is still considered 'my area'). And they say all their pineas are not straight. They promised photos, but couldn't take them because of difficult access at this time of year. I wander maybe this not-straightness is actually natural phenomenon for this species. In my view, maybe it is even desireable to have a tree with such 'defect'. And the coolest thing would be if I could negotiate lower price because of that!

Comment: The specimen they have are 120cm and 250cm high, but larger are not feasible for me to transport (and pay for too). Six people are needed to carry the larger ones!!

Comment: Gees, this must be from heavy snows.  Looks like at least 2 perhaps 3 trees.  Maybe some one covered them with one of those trampolines parents used to buy to entertain their kids?  Even a kiddie swimming pool.  Where is this photo Vivid?  This pine is flexible...do you even have snow?  Something heavy was on top of the little baby pines causing them to grow towards the light.  Grins.  Had to be something heavy during their initial growth years.  Or someone physically manipulated these trees on purpose.  Wind, forget wind.  This is caused by a plant growing to the light...

Comment: Vivid they have 'ball carts' for large trees where one person could move a tree that would take 6?  Hummm.  Do not buy one this large without making sure that the company transports it, plants it correctly and gives you a warranty!  Much more success starting with a tree one person could edge roll and maneuver, using a ball cart and help from a friend. Any tree bigger, I would not purchase without the services of the company. And a warranty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If “effect of winds” needs more explanation, consider roughly this process:

- A young tree grows relatively straight up.
- As it gets larger, it has more foliage and a greater area for the wind to push against, causing it to lean in the predominant direction of the winds.
- At some point, the former trunk is almost flat against the ground.
- The tree decides to turn a now upright side branch into new leader/trunk.
- This process may repeat a few times, leading to the tangled mess of branches/trunks.
- The relatively thin and sandy soils of some coastal areas can contribute to the process as the trees are less “anchored” than elsewhere.
- Winds need not come from one direction only, many coastal areas have strong shifting winds, both during the day and the seasons.
- And pines have not much of a taproot but a more horizontal root system - a bit like a disk -  which can also contribute to leaning.